# Files missing from lbzip2 amd64 package for Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: package-management, 21.10, compression

Installing the lbzip (2.5-2.1build1) package on AMD64 for Ubuntu 21.10 (impish) appears to be missing the actual binaries.

See the file list here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/lbzip2/filelist

Comment: Please file a bug report for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can download and install [`lbzip2` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lbzip2) from 20.04 LTS by

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lbzip2/lbzip2_2.5-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./lbzip2_2.5-2_amd64.deb
```

and pin its version by

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-lbzip2
Package: lbzip2
Pin: version 2.5-2
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

to prevent its unnecessary upgrades.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @BITbyBIT Good to hear that worked for you.  I'd still encourage you to file a bug report on [Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so Canonical can be made aware of the issue.  They don't pick up bug reports here on Ask Ubuntu.  Thanks!

Comment: Done. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lbzip2/+bug/1960413

Apparently I am the first to report this. Also, note that installing the older package as a work around gets overwritten by subsequent updates to that package and the program files removed again, since the newer lbzip2 package is still missing its binary files.

Comment: Thanks, I've added version pinning to the answer.